# How to combine two Node.js App server together.

Tags: node.js, express

I have two apps. which current run in two different ports.

script1.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = require('express').createServer(

         express.cookieParser(),
          // Parses x-www-form-urlencoded request bodies (and json)
          express.bodyParser()  
    )
    ;

app.get('/s1/output', function(sReq, sRes){
    // set cookie

    sRes.send('<div>Out from 1!</div>');
});
```

app.listen(3000);

and here is script2.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = require('express').createServer(

         express.cookieParser(),
          // Parses x-www-form-urlencoded request bodies (and json)
          express.bodyParser()  
    )
    ;

app.get('/s2/output', function(sReq, sRes){
    // set cookie

    sRes.send('<div>Out from 2!</div>');
});
app.listen(3001);
```

ok.. it runs separately on two different ports and have no problem.

Now. the story is that, I can only use port 80 for production.  System Admin doesn't want to open 3000 nor other ports.

Instead of merging code. (in fact, my real code is a lot. and have different config settings for script1 and script2), what can I do to make both of them on port 80? but calling /s1/output will go to script1, and /s2/output will go to script2?

I am thinking about having another scripts. script80.js  that runs on port 80.
and it require both script1, and script2.

But, the question is, what should I export from script 1 and script2?  should I:

```
define all get / post methods, and then, 
module.exports.app =app?
```

and in script80.js, should I do soemthing like that:

```
app.get('/s1/*', function (res, req)) {
   // and what do now?  app1(res) ?
}
```

mmmm

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you have domains or subdomains pointing to this server, you can also use the `vhost` middleware:

```
app.use(express.vhost('s1.domain.com', require('s1').app));
app.use(express.vhost('s2.domain.com', require('s2').app));

app.listen(80);
```

Complete example: https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/examples/vhost/index.js

Comment: Updated url: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/vhost/index.js

Answer (score 5):

You can use nginx listening on port 80 and reverse proxying traffic to the 2 different express app servers behind it.

```
location /s1/ {
    rewrite /s1(.*) $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
}

location /s2/ {
    rewrite /s2(.*) $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
}
```

You could also code this by hand in express as you are asking about, but why reinvent the wheel?